# Set a commands in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to put into DataGrid's cell ListBox of buttons. I googled around DataGrid but found only two things:

1. using DataGridTemplateColumn and set commands in template
2. using DataGridHyperLinkColumn and set event handlers

I tried the first variant(when I click on button it is nothing happens as well as if I use it without ListBox as Button only):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding diffs}">
                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, 
                                                        Path=DataContext.viewSimpleRoute, Mode=OneTime}"
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                                aaa
                                            </Button>

                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListBox>
```

The second variant is not usable for me because I want to make several comand bindings(or event handlers) in a DataGrid's cell. In this way I can only rewrite style of DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle and set only one event handler(as I know I can't set a command here).

---

UPDATE

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tdm:TVZ+SimpleTvzDiffModel}">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button Width="100" Height="23" 
                                            Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.viewSimpleRoute, Mode=OneTime}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                        WORKS
                    </Button>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding diffRoutes}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>                            
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Маршруты">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Width="100" Height="23" 
                                            Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.viewSimpleRoute, Mode=OneTime}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                            DOES NOT WORK
                                        </Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Why?

Comment: Where is the command `viewSimpleRoute` defined?

Comment: Ok, I simplified it. In my program I using ContentPresenter with several DataTemplates in depth of it. I will correct code

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RelayCommand` for binding your Button to your ViewModel.
To simplify the solution i just let out the `ViewModel` and wrote the Propertys in the Window itself.

You should consider to change that.

```
Class MainWindow

      Public Property diffs As List(Of String)
      Public Property ButtonCommand As New RelayCommand(AddressOf ButtonClick)

      Private Sub ButtonClick()
      End Sub

End Class
```

XAML Code:
 (i used diffs for `DataGrid.ItemsSource` as well as for `ListBox.ItemsSource` to simplify it.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    x:Name="Root">
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridButtons" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=diffs}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=diffs}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Width="100" Height="23" Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ButtonCommand, Mode=OneTime}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">aaa</Button>
                  </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
              </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Source for RelayCommand Class:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Input
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class RelayCommand
    Implements ICommand

    ReadOnly _execute As Action(Of Object)
    ReadOnly _canExecute As Predicate(Of Object)

    Public Sub New(execute As Action(Of Object))
        Me.New(execute, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(execute As Action(Of Object), canExecute As Predicate(Of Object))
        If execute Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("execute")
        End If

        _execute = execute
        _canExecute = canExecute
    End Sub

    <DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Public Function CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecute
        Return If(_canExecute Is Nothing, True, _canExecute(parameter))
    End Function

    Public Sub Execute(parameter As Object) Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute
        _execute(parameter)
    End Sub

    Public Sub UpdateCanExecute()
        RaiseEvent CanExecuteChanged(Me, New EventArgs())
    End Sub

    Public Sub RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' To prevent the following calls to invalidate the CanExecuteProperty
    ''' StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    ''' StopCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Custom Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            AddHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
        End AddHandler
        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            RemoveHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event

    'Public Event CanExecuteChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecuteChanged

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something very similar to @BastiOnWpf but changed it slightly within the xaml, as follows;

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RowButtons">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="SomeCommand" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Width="50"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

        <ListView Name="ListView" Height="70" Width="700"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding diffs}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource RowButtons}"/>
                    <!-- Rows goes here-->
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

As you can see, within my Resource, I have set a `datatemplate` where the command you want to be able to add within your `listbox`.

ViewModel;

```
        private ICommand _Command;
        public ICommand SomeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (this._Command == null)
                {
                    this._Command = new new RelayCommand(this.SomeMethod); //The method/procedure you want to use for the listbox
                }
                return this._Command;
            }
        }
```

I have also used a `RelayCommand`, and as you can see I `bind` the item from the view model to the view.

Hope this helps :).